# Is there a faithful linear representation of the additive group of integers?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

In other words, does there (constructively) exist a faithful representation $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow GL_{n}(\mathbb{C}) $?

Comment: It might be worth knowing that while you can still find a faithful representation into $O(n)$ and $U(n)$, the closure if the image will be positive-dimensional! Think about what happens for $U(1)$ and $1 \mapsto e^i$.

Comment: Groups with a (finite-dimensional) faithful linear representation are called linear groups. A fair amount is known about this condition; for example, for finitely generated groups it implies that the group is residually finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure! Take 
$$
\phi(k) = \pmatrix{1&k\\0&1}
$$
for $n = 2$. For $n > 2$, you could of course take
$$
\tilde\phi(k) = \pmatrix{\phi(k) & 0\\0&I_{n-2}}
$$
For $n = 1$, we could always take
$$
\phi(k) = e^k
$$

Comment: D'oh! I tried something similar, but I convinced myself that it wouldn't be possible for some reason. Thanks!